# Copying Indexes From Publisher To Subscriber in SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication, database-administration

I am configuring transactional replication.

I have configured that and its working fine.

Now i want to copy all the non clustered indexes and covered indexes(NC Index)
from publisher to subscriber.

Any approach followed by people to do that stuff with too much overhead.

Comment: You don't need to replicate indexes. You can create them manually without comprising replication (as long as you don't touch the primary key). This means your indexing strategy can best reflect the requirements of the subscription server i.e. reporting.

Comment: Sorry type-o. Compromising.

Answer (score 0):

You can have replication take care of this automatically for you when you create a table article. As long as whatever value you're specifying for `@schema_option` in the call to `sp_addarticle` contains 0x40, the snapshot script will contain the relevant `create index` statements.

That said, for existing articles, the comment on the question made by @pacreely is completely correct; as long as you don't touch the primary key, you can pretty much do whatever you want. That is, if you're doing replication to support a reporting workload, you can add indexes only to your subscribed database and not have to add them to your published database.